# CS50: I can't open the JPG's my image recovery program creates

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50

As I said in the title I can't open the JPG's my image recovery program creates. The purpose of this program is to scan the argument infile for JPEGs a 512 byte block at a time. If the block signals the start of a new file the program should close the last outfile, open a new outfile and start writing into it. If the data in the block is not the start of a new file, the program should continue writing into the current outfile. My program creates 50 files which is the amount of photos in the infile. However, when I try to open them I am told "Invalid or Unsupported Image Format".

Could anyone offer any advice as I am a little stumped?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

BYTE block[512];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
    {
      printf("Usage: ./recover filename\n");
      return 1;
    }

  char *card = argv[1];
  FILE *raw_data = fopen(card, "r");

  if (raw_data == NULL)
    {
      printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
      return 1;
    }

  char file_name[8];
  BYTE buffer[512];
  int counter = 0;
  FILE *image = NULL;

  while (fread(buffer, sizeof(block), 1, raw_data) != 0)
    {
      if (counter == 0)
    {
      sprintf(file_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
      image = fopen(file_name, "w");
      fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(block), 1, image);
      counter++;
    }

      else if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
      fclose(image);
      sprintf(file_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
      image = fopen(file_name, "w");
      counter++;
    }
      else
    {
      fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(block), 1, image);
    }
    }

  fclose(raw_data);
  fclose(image);
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of your question is in this else if statement.

```
else if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            fclose(image);
            sprintf(file_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            image = fopen(file_name, "w");
            counter++;
        }
```

When there is a jpeg signature in the beginning of each 512 byte block, this statement is executed. You close the image file if it is open before. You create a new image file, and you open it for writing. But then?? You **did not write** the buffer on image file where it has jpeg signature.. Bam! Your jpeg file is not supported! How can a computer know if it is jpeg without a jpeg signature?

There are other problems in while loop. Even if you fixed the main issue, you first jpeg file will be just garbage.. Why? Look at this if statement below. It is writing the very first 512 byte block of raw file without any check if it carries jpeg signature or not.

```
if (counter == 0)
{
    sprintf(file_name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
    image = fopen(file_name, "w");
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(block), 1, image);
    counter++;
}
```

The very first `if statement` in while loop should rather be to **check** if the 512 byte memory block has the jpeg signature or not.  A pseudo code for a new design would help you. Because you probably want to fix other issues by yourself.

```
//If the buffer starts with the magic sequence found in the original code.
    //If there is already an image found, then close. (Check if counter is not equal to zero.
    //Create a new jpeg file.
    //Open that new jpeg file.
//Write buffer on new jpeg file. This one should be outside of the main if statement.
```

Good luck with solving other issues. You are pretty close.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help. I've applied some of your changes. I'm just struggling with the while loop right now. I'm suffering a segmentation fault so I'll need to teak it a little.

Comment: Segmentation fault means you are trying to read a NULL location in the memory. Memory does not allow this. Check same segmentation problem and solution from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923224/pset-4-recover-segmentation-fault-cs50/61406493#61406493

Comment: I already finished my program. I can't thank you enough for the help though.